# C# export SQL Server large tables in batches/chunks using DataReader and CSV writer

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldatareader, bcp, csvhelper

I developed a CSV batch writer.
But the process seems to be pretty slow compared to the BCP.
The only requirement I have is to export big tables without identity or primary key columns into multiple small sized CSV files and name them with corresponding batch id.

The issue with BCP is that it will only write to a single big file.

What my current process does is:
Reads the data and using CSV writer writes into memory stream
I am continuously checking if the memory stream is greater than a particular batch size then I will copy the memory stream asynchronously write to a text file.

Without out of memory exceptions I am able to export a batch size of 250MB files

But this process takes 5 times more time compared to BCP export.

Is there any better way to achieve the batch exporting to CSV than what I am doing.

Please advise.

Comment: `The issue with bcp is that it will only write to a single big file.` Write to a single file. Write a separate process to split the single file into multiple smaller files. I can almost guarantee it will wipe the floor, performance wise, with the approach you are considering.

Comment: Haven't tested splitting the files after export
But from what I read it takes a good amount of time to split the large files into smaller files as it has to go through the entire file in order to split it

Comment: +1 for mjwillis but, BCP is compatible with batching - you just have to run it once per batch. `FETCH NEXT N ROWS` and `OFFSET N ROWS` should work.

Comment: Splitting a CSV by number of records is a task that should be able to be done with IO as the bottleneck. A state machine reader would just have to ignore quoted CRLF’s, and split on number of unquoted CRLFs. For bonus points, do a steaming bulk copy and split on the fly (avoiding the extra write+read and storage space of the full file being written to disk)

Comment: Hi Mitch, l liked the bonus point idea
Can you elaborate that one for me please
I thought I have the same process built
But when writing to file after certain size of data is streamed I am storing it in memory stream and writing it asynchronously to file. This way I am having memory out of space issues. Can I get away with memory stream and still split the stream into multiple parts?

Comment: Fetch N rows and offset n rows: would that not be time consuming if we don't have a primary key or identity column in that large 100gb table ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple options come to mind:

### Use FETCH / OFFSET

If the source query is able to be batched in SQL Server easily (e.g. a clustered index that you can key off of), FETCH and OFFSET are basically free.

If the table is a heap, FETCH/OFFSET are not really an option, but you might consider adding a clustered index since there are not too many good arguments against doing so (though doing so for a 100 GB table would be expensive :)

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM DemoTable ORDER BY ClusteredKey OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY" queryout fetch1.csv -S Server -U sa -P Password -w
bcp "SELECT * FROM DemoTable ORDER BY ClusteredKey OFFSET 20000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY" queryout fetch2.csv -S Server -U sa -P Password -w
bcp "SELECT * FROM DemoTable ORDER BY ClusteredKey OFFSET 40000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY" queryout fetch3.csv -S Server -U sa -P Password -w
bcp "SELECT * FROM DemoTable ORDER BY ClusteredKey OFFSET 60000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20000 ROWS ONLY" queryout fetch4.csv -S Server -U sa -P Password -w
```

### Use SqlDataReader

From measurements using a table of ~1.2 GB, a naïve implementation of a C# CSV SQL Export (below) achieves 75% of the performance of BCP on the same table and system.  (It also has the benefit of [handling the CSV format correctly](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32894029-bcp-utility-should-support-rfc-4180-csv-files) regarding embedded commas, quotes, and CRLF's).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var con = new SqlConnection(@"Server=(local);Database=Demo;User Id=sa;Password=bar;");
    con.Open();

    var sqr = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.Table", con);

    using (var reader = sqr.ExecuteReader())
    using (var tw = File.CreateText("out.csv"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    tw.Write(',');
                }

                var val = FormatValue(reader[i]);
                if (val == null)
                {
                    // no-op
                }
                else if (val.IndexOfAny(new[] { '"', ',', '\r', '\n' }) >= 0)
                {
                    tw.Write('"');
                    tw.Write(val.Replace("\"", "\"\""));
                    tw.Write('"');
                }
                else
                {
                    tw.Write(val);
                }
            }
            tw.Write("\r\n");
        }
    }
}

private static string FormatValue(object v)
{
    if (v == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if (v is DateTime dt)
    {
        return dt.ToString("O");
    }
    if (v is DateTimeOffset dto)
    {
        return dto.ToString("O");
    }
    if (v is byte[] ba)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder(2 + ba.Length * 2);
        sb.Append("0x");
        for (int i = 0; i < ba.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(ba[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    return v.ToString();
}
```

Performance seems to be limited by the GC handling so many string allocations - so if higher performance is required, the same translated to a non-CLR language (e.g. C++) would probably match the performance of BCP.

### Use SSIS

SSIS can perform all the steps in one package.  The exact steps are probably best left to a different question, but basically amount to synthesizing a column for "File number" and using the Flat File destination.  [Bad example of this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3172.split-a-flat-text-file-into-multiple-flat-text-files-using-ssis.aspx)

### Use SSIS to generate a big CSV, then split it

If you use SSIS (either directly or by [using the Export Data Wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-management-studio-ssms)), you will get a RFC 4180 compliant CSV File that you can split.  An example tool to split such a file would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0;
        using (var src = File.OpenRead("rfc4180_in.csv"))
        using (var dst = new CsvRfc4180SplittingWriteStream(() => File.Create($"rfc4180_out{n++}.csv"), 100 /* mb per chunk */ * 1024 * 1024))
        {
            src.CopyTo(dst);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Abstract class which uses ParseDataGetCutPoint to split the files into streams at least 
/// cutAfterPosition bytes long.
/// </summary>
abstract class SplittingWriteStream : Stream
{
    private long _TotalPosition;
    private long CurrentStreamPos;
    private readonly long CutAfterPosition;
    private readonly Func<Stream> StreamCtor;
    private Stream CurrentStream;

    public SplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
    {
        if (cutAfterPosition < 0L)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(cutAfterPosition));
        }
        this.CutAfterPosition = cutAfterPosition;

        this.StreamCtor = createStream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createStream));
        this.CurrentStream = createStream();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) => CurrentStream.Dispose();

    public override void Flush() => CurrentStream.Flush();

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // ignore count to always exceed cutAfterPosition
        var cutPoint = ParseDataGetCutPoint(buffer, offset, count, getCutPoint: CurrentStreamPos > CutAfterPosition);
        if (cutPoint < 0)
        {
            CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cutPoint > 0)
            {
                CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset, cutPoint);
            }

            try
            {
                CurrentStream.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                CurrentStream = null;
                CurrentStreamPos = 0L;
                CurrentStream = StreamCtor();
            }

            if (cutPoint != count)
            {
                CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset + cutPoint, count - cutPoint);
            }
        }

        CurrentStreamPos += count;
        _TotalPosition += count;
    }

    protected abstract int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint);

    #region Stream Write-only stubs

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Position
    {
        get => _TotalPosition;
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

class CsvRfc4180SplittingWriteStream : SplittingWriteStream
{
    public CsvRfc4180SplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
        : base(createStream, cutAfterPosition)
    {
    }

    bool inQuotedString;
    bool lastWasQuote;
    protected override int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint)
    {
        int? cutPoint = null;
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        {
            var i = n + offset;
            StepState(buffer[i]);

            // check for CRLF if desired and not escaped
            if (getCutPoint && !inQuotedString && cutPoint == null
                && buffer[i] == '\r' && n + 1 < count && buffer[i + 1] == '\n')
            {
                cutPoint = n;
            }
        }

        return cutPoint ?? -1;
    }

    private void StepState(byte v)
    {
        var isQuote = v == '"';
        if (lastWasQuote)
        {
            lastWasQuote = false;

            if (isQuote)
            {
                // Double quotes:
                //  nop
                //  Inside quoted string == literal escape
                //  Outside quoted string == empty string
            }
            else
            {
                // quote with non-quote following == toggle quoted string
                inQuotedString ^= true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastWasQuote = isQuote;
        }
    }
}
```

### Use BCP, then split on the fly

If BCP is desired, and its (bad) handling of CSV is tolerable, it can write to a named pipe stream to split on the fly.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread copyThread;
        var pipeId = $"bcp_{Guid.NewGuid():n}";
        // bcp requires read/write pipe
        using (var np = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeId))
        {
            copyThread = new Thread(_1 =>
            {
                np.WaitForConnection();
                int n = 0;
                // Use CrlfUtf16leSplittingWriteStream with -w (UTF 16 Little Endian)
                // Use CrlfUtf8SplittingWriteStream other (UTF 8 / ANSII / ASCII / OEM)
                using (var dst = new CrlfUtf16leSplittingWriteStream(() => File.Create($"rfc4180_out{n++}.csv"), 100 /* mb per chunk */ * 1024 * 1024))
                {
                    np.CopyTo(dst);
                }
            });
            copyThread.Name = "Write thread";
            copyThread.IsBackground = true;
            copyThread.Start();

            var bcp = Process.Start(
                @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe",
                $@"FWDB.Rx.RxBatches out \\.\pipe\{pipeId} -S (local) -U sa -P abc -w -t,");
            bcp.WaitForExit();
        }
        copyThread.Join();
    }
}

class CrlfUtf16leSplittingWriteStream : SplittingWriteStream
{
    public CrlfUtf16leSplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
        : base(createStream, cutAfterPosition)
    {
    }

    protected override int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint)
    {
        if (getCutPoint)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < count - 3 /* CR 00 LF 00 */; n++)
            {
                var i = n + offset;
                if (buffer[i] == '\r' && buffer[i + 1] == 0
                    && buffer[i + 2] == '\n' && buffer[i + 3] == 0)
                {
                    // split after CRLF
                    return n + 4;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}

class CrlfUtf8SplittingWriteStream : SplittingWriteStream
{
    public CrlfUtf8SplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
        : base(createStream, cutAfterPosition)
    {
    }

    protected override int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint)
    {
        if (getCutPoint)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < count - 1 /* CR LF */; n++)
            {
                var i = n + offset;
                if (buffer[i] == '\r' && buffer[i + 1] == '\n')
                {
                    // split after CRLF
                    return n + 2;
                }
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Abstract class which uses ParseDataGetCutPoint to split the files into streams at least 
/// cutAfterPosition bytes long.
/// </summary>
abstract class SplittingWriteStream : Stream
{
    private long _TotalPosition;
    private long CurrentStreamPos;
    private readonly long CutAfterPosition;
    private readonly Func<Stream> StreamCtor;
    private Stream CurrentStream;

    public SplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
    {
        if (cutAfterPosition < 0L)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(cutAfterPosition));
        }
        this.CutAfterPosition = cutAfterPosition;

        this.StreamCtor = createStream ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(createStream));
        this.CurrentStream = createStream();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) => CurrentStream.Dispose();

    public override void Flush() => CurrentStream.Flush();

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // ignore count to always exceed cutAfterPosition
        var cutPoint = ParseDataGetCutPoint(buffer, offset, count, getCutPoint: CurrentStreamPos > CutAfterPosition);
        if (cutPoint < 0)
        {
            CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cutPoint > 0)
            {
                CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset, cutPoint);
            }

            try
            {
                CurrentStream.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                CurrentStream = null;
                CurrentStreamPos = 0L;
                CurrentStream = StreamCtor();
            }

            if (cutPoint != count)
            {
                CurrentStream.Write(buffer, offset + cutPoint, count - cutPoint);
            }
        }

        CurrentStreamPos += count;
        _TotalPosition += count;
    }

    protected abstract int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint);

    #region Stream Write-only stubs

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanSeek => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override long Length => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => throw new NotSupportedException();
    public override void SetLength(long value) => throw new NotSupportedException();

    public override long Position
    {
        get => _TotalPosition;
        set => throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    #endregion
}

class CsvRfc4180SplittingWriteStream : SplittingWriteStream
{
    public CsvRfc4180SplittingWriteStream(Func<Stream> createStream, long cutAfterPosition)
        : base(createStream, cutAfterPosition)
    {
    }

    bool inQuotedString;
    bool lastWasQuote;
    protected override int ParseDataGetCutPoint(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, bool getCutPoint)
    {
        int? cutPoint = null;
        for (int n = 0; n < count; n++)
        {
            var i = n + offset;
            StepState(buffer[i]);

            // check for CRLF if desired and not escaped
            if (getCutPoint && !inQuotedString && cutPoint == null
                && buffer[i] == '\r' && n + 1 < count && buffer[i + 1] == '\n')
            {
                cutPoint = n;
            }
        }

        return cutPoint ?? -1;
    }

    private void StepState(byte v)
    {
        var isQuote = v == '"';
        if (lastWasQuote)
        {
            lastWasQuote = false;

            if (isQuote)
            {
                // Double quotes:
                //  nop
                //  Inside quoted string == literal escape
                //  Outside quoted string == empty string
            }
            else
            {
                // quote with non-quote following == toggle quoted string
                inQuotedString ^= true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lastWasQuote = isQuote;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much
This answer will definitely be helpful to many people in future

Comment: I am not able to upvote the answer as my reputation points are less
Thanks again!